# Hyperlink base link

Tags: html, hyperlink, href

I have a link that I want to go to
`something.com/one/two`
I try to do the following

```
<a href = "one/two">Link</a>
```

When clicked from `something.com` then it does go to `something.com/one/two` when clicked from `something.com/one` then it goes to `something.com/one/one/two`.
Is there any way to specify one `a href` so that it can go to `something.com/one/two`? I do not want href to be `something.com/one/two`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a forward slash to beginning so that it starts from the root:

```
<a href="/one/two">Link</a>
```